# Link with password is not sent to the new user

Tags: wp-admin, user-registration, email-verification

We are having the issue with email - is not sent when new user registers. The password link is not emailed to the user.

We are using g suite and never had any issues on wp

If anyone can help that would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried installing an email log program, so you can verify whether the email is not *sent* or not *received*?

Comment: no, do you have any suggestion in program to use?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so we figured it. If you are using g suite - it requires SMTP plugin. We used  the free one called WP MAIL SMTP and then contacted g suite support to configure it but this article gives a good answer to it as well:
https://www.siteground.com/tutorials/wordpress/use-smtp/